# How can I avoid 'make install' when building PHP in Unix environment?

Tags: php, unix, installation, makefile

I'm attempting to rapidly deploy a PHP application under apache2/PHP on a Unix host.  The sysadmin *hasn't heard of PHP* so I'm looking to build/install myself.  Unfortunately root access is two weeks of bureaucracy away so I'm looking for a way to use PHP and its requisite libxml2 without installing.

Comment: Why do you want to build instead of downloading a pre-built binary?

Comment: sysadmin should do his job, make him install libxml2, in many system It only needs to a line of code like "yum install libxml2". By the way did you heard of serverfault?

Comment: You can't use a program without installing it. You'll save yourself many headaches over the next year by waiting the two weeks for root access. Wait.Your sysadmin has never heard of PHP??? And doesn't have root access to the box he's admining??? Sounds like someone avoided running `make install` when they made **him!**

Comment: @ircmaxell: I meant that part tongue-in-cheek ;)

Comment: Hadn't thought of using yum - again because of root privileges.  The sysadmin did me a favour and installed PHP but of course I'm now missing libphp5.so.  Anybody know whether there is a way of getting that, again avoiding `make install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be a non-privileged user and build [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html) and [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php).  You can have your own prefix paths for the installs, and if the development headers for the necessary libraries are available you can use them.  You're going to hit issues in that as not-root you'll have to start Apache on a port > 1024.  You're also not going to have the system package management available, so updates will have to be likewise built.  In short, it's doable, but depending on which UNIX you're actually using, may not be horrendously pleasant.  PHP in particular needs many many libraries (and if you're building from source, runtime isn't enough, you need the dev headers files) to have a usable system.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid `make install`, but you can maybe use `--prefix`